# Dart HTTP Post with Complex Object as body

Tags: json, http, flutter, post, dart

The Dart http package's post method only accepts a String, a List or a Map as the request body. I need to send this list as body

```
     List item = widget.product
    .map((prod) => {
    "product_id": prod.id,
  "product_name": prod.title,
"product_quantity": prod.quantity,
"product_reference": prod.reference
   }).toList();
```

In Postman I would build the body as raw json

```
{"id_customer": "null",
"id_adresse": "null",
"id_carrier": "155",
"secure_key": "null",
"payment": "Paiement à la livraison",
"total_paid": "311.0",
"total_product": "298.0",
"total_shipping": "7.0",
"tax": "0.6",
"products": [{"product_id": "5444",
            "product_name": "Batterie adaptable pour ordinateur portable  Asus X550A 2200mAh",
            "product_quantity": "1",
            "product_reference": "null"},
            {"product_id": "5433",
            "product_name": "Batterie originale pour ordinateur portable Asus K52 4400mAh",
            "product_quantity": "1",
            "product_reference": "null"}]}
```

and this my try

```
void addorders(String id , String id_adresse,String secure_key,String id_carrier,String paiement,double total,double total_product,double total_shipping,double tax, List products) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key ) ?? 0;

    String myUrl =  "$serverUrl/orders";
final String prod=products.toString();

    http.post(myUrl,
        headers: {
          'Accept':'application/json',
          //"content-type": "application/json",
          'Authorization' : 'JWT $value'
        },
        body: {
          "id_customer":"$id",
          "id_adresse":"$id_adresse",
          "id_carrier":"$id_carrier",
          "secure_key":"$secure_key",
          "payment":"$paiement",
          "total_paid":"$total",
          "total_product":"$total_product",
          "total_shipping":"$total_shipping",
          "tax":"$tax",
          "products":"$prod",

        }).then((response){
     // print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body ');
      print(response.request);

     // print('Response body : ${id_carrier}');
    }
    );
  }
```

I Use String encoded = json.encode(theMap) but same problem 
my api don't read the list products
Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You should use converters to get dart classes that math your json data and deal with it instead of passing your values like you do.

You can use this [JSON to Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) for example. You just have to paste your json data from postman to get your dart class back

After you will just have to call the `toJson()` method of your class to get the Map for the body of your request